# Is it correct to express possessive form of the word "past"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, punctuation

The title a colleague came up with shows a possessive form of the word past - but it sounds off to me. Is this correct and if not, how do you suggest I phrase it instead?

> Melt the weight by breaking free of the past’s hold on our body

Comment: There is no issue with what you have.

Comment: It's certainly grammatical, but I agree it doesn't sound wonderful. It wasn't the past that had you in its grip. 'The past's amazing diversity of civilisations' doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: The end of the sentence bothers me. "... the past's hold on **our** body."? Shouldn't that be either 'our bodies. or 'your body'?

Comment: @Norman To me it sounds poetic and similar to the royal "we," the majestic plural.

Comment: There's certainly nothing wrong with it.  And, as Zan700 suggests, "past's hold" has a certain poetic sense to it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct to me, but I suppose one could say "Melt the weight by breaking the hold of the past on your body", if that sounds better to you.

Comment: I like that tweak a lot. It sounds much better to me. Thanks!